# What would be the easiest way to generate new localized resource files?

Tags: winforms, resources, localization

My windows forms application consists of one Visual Studio solution and several projects.  The application is localized in English and French using resource files (each project has global resource files, e.g. fooResources.resx and fooResources.fr.resx, and each form/user control has its own resource files (e.g. fooForm.resx and fooForm.fr.resx) - so lets say for arguments sake I have about 30 sets of resource files.

I now have to extract all the strings to be sent for translation into German, then when I receive the translated strings create German resource files (e.g. fooResources.de.resx and fooForm.de.resx) which contain the new captions.

Obviously I could do all of this manually, but I am a developer and thus by nature lazy!  No, just kidding - but I would appreciate some suggestions on the most painless way to do this as I am sure more languages will be coming in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of a translation product that makes the job very easy for both the developer and the translator. See http://www.hexadigm.com.

Comment: "TranSolution consists of two applications, a Visual Studio add-in that programmers will use to bundle up all strings in their solution into a single file for shipping to a translator, and a simple yet powerful application that the translator will use to read this file and translate the strings (translators may obtain a free, permanent copy of this on our free downloads page - no "strings" attached). After translation is complete, the same add-in is then used to import these strings back into the programmer's solution." - 

This sounds too good to be true!  I'll take a look...

Comment: Larry's product did exactly what I was looking for.  Great product and exceptional support.

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with this a few different ways. I have worked with translators that are more than willing to work with .ResX files and will create the files as needed (though you may have to rename them to the proper locale code.

Otherwise, the contents of the resource files are purely XML. I wrote a little program that drops the xml data into a datagrid, and then imports the CSV or Excel file in using the key as a UID.